# Using Python threading to monitor sensors

Tags: python, multithreading, python-2.7, class, arduino

**Objective:** Use threading to build independent Python sensor classes to handle communication between Raspberry Pi and Arduino sensors and some basic data processing.

**Background:**

I have an Arduino MEGA with some sensors on it, and a Raspberry Pi 3 running python. The Pi sends a request to the Arduino to read one of its sensor values. My Arduino has encoders, motors, lights, pumps, etc, so I have created a generalized python class to handle each type of peripheral.

Each python class will read the raw sensor value, store it in a log, and do some calculations.

```
import time
import numpy as np

class Encoder(object):
    def __init__(self, hex_address):
        self.hex_address = hex_address
        self.log = []

    def read(self):
        observation = (time.time(), raw_value())
        log.append(observation)

    def raw_value(self):
        ...Communication code...
        return value

    def speed(self, over=1.0):
        times = [obs[0] for obs in self.log if time.time() - obs[0] < over]
        rates = [obs[1] for obs in self.log if time.time() - obs[0] < over]
        return np.polyfit(times, rates, 1)[0]
```

I then have the main loop of my program

```
enc = Encoder('\x04')

while True:
    print enc.read()
    print enc.speed()
    times.sleep(1)
```

**The Problem:**

In this setup, for the `Encoder()` class to really function properly, something has to call `enc.read()` at a semi-regular basis, or else data points won't get added to the log.

Further, what if various parts of my program call `enc.read()`. Now I'm getting more or less data depending on when and where I call `enc.read()`.

Also, every time I call `enc.speed()`, my Pi has to calculate another `np.polyfit`, even if the data hasn't changed.

**The Goal:** implement threading to launch a new thread for each sensor object.

That way they run independently of my main thread. I would like to `start()` the sensor, and then have it add new data to the log by calling `read()` every X ms. Further, I may implement an `update()` method that does the reading and all the calculations each time it's called.

**What I need help with:**

I have played around with some threaded classes, but am having a lot of trouble weaving threading into this sample code.